# Another user is not adding in the Banned Members

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a Blog Group App, In which users can make group about blogs and only one admin. Admin ban the members. BUT when i try to ban a user then it is saving some other user. Like there are 2 users and when i try to ban `user_1` then `user_2` is saving.

AND sometimes it says **Page Not Found(404)**. AND then i reset my database. Sometimes it says **Group object query doesn't exist**.

I have no idea what is wrong in the code, I have tried many times but failed.

models.py

```
class Group(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='')
    banned_members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='banned_members', blank=True)

class GroupPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='')
```

views.py

```
def bans(request,pk):
    group = get_object_or_404(Group,pk=pk)
    post = get_object_or_404(GroupPost,pk=pk)
    group.banned_members.add(post.user)
    return redirect('home')

def GroupDetailView(request,pk):
    data = get_object_or_404(Group,pk=pk)
    posts = data.grouppost_set.order_by('-date_added')

    context = {'data':data,'posts':posts}
    return render(request, 'detail_group.html',context)
```

urls.py

```
path('bans/<int:pk>/', views.bans, name='bans'),
```

detail_group.html

```
{% for pos in posts %}


<a href="{{ pos.get_absolute_url }}">{{ pos.post_title }}</a>


<b>User :</b>{{ pos.user }}<a href="{% url 'bans' user.id %}">BAN</a>


{% endfor %}
```

I am trying to ban user

I have no idea what i am doing wrong.

Any help would really be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your view:

User.objects.get(user=request.user). banned_members.add(pk)